# Using the convexhull function in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement Convexhull in my python project but I am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "contourfeaturestest.py", line 22, in <module>
hull2 = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
cv2.error:convhull.cpp:134: error: (-215) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function convexHull
```

I am trying to use convexhull with frames that come from the computer's video camera and I am not sure why my code is producing the error above.

My code is provided below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    ret1,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,0)
    contours,hierarchy,ret2= cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
    cnt = contours[0] 
    hull2 = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can guess by your code, it seems that you are using `Opencv3.1`, under which the return value from `cv2.findContours()` has been changed to: `ret_image, contours, hierarchy` as opposed to what you are assuming it to be: `contours,hierarchy,ret2` So basically the second value in the returned tuple contains the list of contours.

However, in the previous OpenCV version `cv2.findContours()` returned only 2 values: `contours, hierarchy`, so a slight change in the naming conventions would work for you.